# How to detect when the title is updated by AJAX in a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

In an app, I have a couple of links to our website (which has a jQuery mobile version) that I want to open up in the app.

I use my own view controller and add a UIWebView on, like so:

```
webv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367)];
[webv setDelegate:self];
[webv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
[self.view addSubview:webv];
```

I'm also using a nav controller, so I want to update the title when the page loads:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    self.title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

However, because jQuery mobile makes requests via AJAX and calls `history.pushState`, then the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method never gets triggered.

So, how can I update my nav controller when the page title gets changed via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set you navigation title from this method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{}
```

Comment: This will NOT work for intercepting/listening to AJAX calls.